# Blender correctly text the image on object

Tags: mapping, textures, blender

Is it possible in BLENDER version 2.82a to adjust the texture so that the corners of the tower are not moved up or down so that they fit correctly? Sorry for the bad English I use the translator. I'm attaching pictures. Thank you for the advice.I am a beginner.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. But you would need a **seamless texture** so it can repeat itself over the object. This is what happens when I copy and paste the texture multiple times next to each other:

[image: The seams are clerly visible]

The seams are clerly visible.

Answer (score 0):

And any instructions for proper mapping? I've looked at the tutorials everywhere, but somehow I can't